# Tangent line to a Graph

Tags: calculus

Given is the function $y = e^x\ln x$ and for this function the tangent line at the root of the function must be found.

As far as I can see the root is at $x = 1.$
So the point through which the tangent goes is $(1,\,0).$ Then for the slope of the tangent line I calculate the derivative of the function for which I get $e^x\ln x + \dfrac{e^x}{x}$ and plug $x = 1$ into the derivative and hence get $e$ as the slope. Also, I get $e$ for the tangent's $y$-intercept.

Hence I get $y = ex + e$ for the tangent line.

Is this correct? Seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine except for the $y$ intercept.  Given that the slope is $e$ and the line goes through $(1,0)$ the point-slope form gives $y-0=e(x-1)=ex-e$ so the $y$ intercept is $-e$